# Can't handle with the movement bug in simple Java.swing game

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, game-physics

I have a problem with moving in the game I am creating, everything works exactly as I would like except one thing, the board is redrawn according to the timer delay and when I do more than one move before board redraws, then there is a chance that my snake will fall into itself each other. I can not handle this and I do not know how to avoid it, I was thinking about setting a delay between push buttons but it is impossible because the game is for two players. I'm trying to fix this issue where the snake backtracks into itself, but haven't found a solution yet. Any help would be appreciated.

**Several photos representing the problem:**

**Normal gameplay:**
[image]

When i spam the buttons:
[image]

**Movement method:**

```
    private void move()
{

    for (int z = dots; z > 0; z--)
    {
        p1x[z] = p1x[(z - 1)];
        p1y[z] = p1y[(z - 1)];
        p2x[z] = p2x[(z - 1)];
        p2y[z] = p2y[(z - 1)];
    }

    if (p1LeftDirection)
    {
        p1x[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
    }

    if (p1RightDirection)
    {
        p1x[0] += DOT_SIZE;
    }

    if (p1UpDirection)
    {
        p1y[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
    }

    if (p1DownDirection)
    {
        p1y[0] += DOT_SIZE;
    }

    if (p2LeftDirection)
    {
        p2x[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
    }

    if (p2RightDirection)
    {
        p2x[0] += DOT_SIZE;
    }

    if (p2UpDirection)
    {
        p2y[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
    }

    if (p2DownDirection)
    {
        p2y[0] += DOT_SIZE;
    }
    dots++;
}
```

**Drawing method:**

```
private void doDrawing(Graphics g)
{
    if (inGame)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++)
        {
            if (z == 0)
            {
                g.drawImage(p1Head, p1x[z], p1y[z], this);
                g.drawImage(p2Head, p2x[z], p2y[z], this);
            }
            else
            {
                g.drawImage(p1Body, p1x[z], p1y[z], this);
                g.drawImage(p2Body, p2x[z], p2y[z], this);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < B_WIDTH; i += 25)
        {
            g.drawImage(brick, 0, i, this);
            g.drawImage(brick, i, 0, this);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < B_WIDTH; i += 25)
        {
            g.drawImage(brick, B_WIDTH - DOT_SIZE, i, this);
            g.drawImage(brick, i, B_HEIGHT - DOT_SIZE, this);
        }

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }
    else
    {
        gameOver(g);
    }
}
```

**And my KeyAdapter:**

```
public class KeyboardSettings extends KeyAdapter
{

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) && (!p1RightDirection))
        {
            ImageIcon p1HeadLoader = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/images/p1leftmouth.png");
            p1Head = p1HeadLoader.getImage();
            p1LeftDirection = true;
            p1UpDirection = false;
            p1DownDirection = false;
        }

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) && (!p1LeftDirection))
        {
            ImageIcon p1HeadLoader = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/images/p1rightmouth.png");
            p1Head = p1HeadLoader.getImage();
            p1RightDirection = true;
            p1UpDirection = false;
            p1DownDirection = false;
        }

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) && (!p1DownDirection))
        {
            ImageIcon p1HeadLoader = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/images/p1upmouth.png");
            p1Head = p1HeadLoader.getImage();
            p1UpDirection = true;
            p1RightDirection = false;
            p1LeftDirection = false;
        }

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) && (!p1UpDirection))
        {
            ImageIcon p1HeadLoader = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/images/p1downmouth.png");
            p1Head = p1HeadLoader.getImage();
            p1DownDirection = true;
            p1RightDirection = false;
            p1LeftDirection = false;
        }

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_A) && (!p2RightDirection))
        {
            ImageIcon p2HeadLoader = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/images/p2leftmouth.png");
            p2Head = p2HeadLoader.getImage();
            p2LeftDirection = true;
            p2UpDirection = false;
            p2DownDirection = false;
        }

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_D) && (!p2LeftDirection))
        {
            ImageIcon p2HeadLoader = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/images/p2rightmouth.png");
            p2Head = p2HeadLoader.getImage();
            p2RightDirection = true;
            p2UpDirection = false;
            p2DownDirection = false;
        }

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_W) && (!p2DownDirection))
        {
            ImageIcon p2HeadLoader = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/images/p2upmouth.png");
            p2Head = p2HeadLoader.getImage();
            p2UpDirection = true;
            p2RightDirection = false;
            p2LeftDirection = false;
        }

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_S) && (!p2UpDirection))
        {
            ImageIcon p2HeadLoader = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/images/p2downmouth.png");
            p2Head = p2HeadLoader.getImage();
            p2DownDirection = true;
            p2RightDirection = false;
            p2LeftDirection = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know the source of your error or even what your error is (are you trying to prevent the snake from going back on itself?), but one huge problem I see is that you're reading and re-reading your images hundreds of times within your KeyAdapater -- why on earth do this? Why not read the images **once** and store them in a variable for repeated use?

Comment: Yes i'm trying to prevent from going snake back on itself. With the pictures u have right, i'll fix that, i'm just begginer in programming.

Comment: Then your problem is not a GUI problem, and GUI solutions as you're proposing will fail, but rather, it's a logic problem -- how to prevent the snake from overlapping itself. To solve this you're going to have to work on the logic side of things -- testing where the snake is moving to next and checking that it's a valid location before allowing it to occur.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i think thats GUI problem because the game doesn't allow you for exaple for move left when are u currently moving in right direction. To move snake back to itself when u moving in right direction u need to press up then left then down arrow in one timer cycle (for now 150ms), before the board repaints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. I tried different in-built methods but they didn't work for me. But this is how I would bypass the problem with my method:

```
private void move()
{

for (int z = dots; z > 0; z--)
{
    p1x[z] = p1x[(z - 1)];
    p1y[z] = p1y[(z - 1)];
    p2x[z] = p2x[(z - 1)];
    p2y[z] = p2y[(z - 1)];
}

if (p1LeftDirection)
{
    p1x[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
    if(p1x[0] == p1x[2])
    {
        p1x[0] += 2*DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();
    }
    else if(p1x[0] == p1x[1])
    {
        p1x[0] += DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();
    }
}

if (p1RightDirection)
{
    p1x[0] += DOT_SIZE;
    if(p1x[0] == p1x[2])
    {
        p1x[0] -= 2*DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();
    }
    else if(p1x[0] == p1x[1])
    {
        p1x[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();
    }
}

if (p1UpDirection)
{
    p1y[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
    if(p1y[0] == p1y[2])
    {
        p1y[0] += 2*DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();
    }
    else if(p1y[0] == p1y[1])
    {
        p1y[0] += DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();

    }
}

if (p1DownDirection)
{
    p1y[0] += DOT_SIZE;
    if(p1y[0] == p1y[2])
    {
        p1y[0] -= 2*DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();
    }
    else if(p1y[0] == p1y[1])
    {
        p1y[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();
    }
}

if (p2LeftDirection)
{
    p2x[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
    if(p2x[0] == p2x[2])
    {
        p2x[0] += 2*DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();
    }
    else if(p2x[0] == p2x[1])
    {
        p2x[0] += DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();
    }
}

if (p2RightDirection)
{
    p2x[0] += DOT_SIZE;
    if(p2x[0] == p2x[2])
    {
        p2x[0] -= 2*DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();
    }
    else if(p2x[0] == p2x[1])
    {
        p2x[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();
    }
}

if (p2UpDirection)
{
    p2y[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
    if(p2y[0] == p2y[2])
    {
        p2y[0] += 2*DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();
    }
    else if(p2y[0] == p2y[1])
    {
        p2y[0] += DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();
    }
}

if (p2DownDirection)
{
    p2y[0] += DOT_SIZE;
    if(p2y[0] == p2y[2])
    {
        p2y[0] -= 2*DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();
    }
    else if(p2y[0] == p2y[1])
    {
        p2y[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
        rotateCorr();
    }
}
dots++;
}
```

I know exactly the glitch you faced, so this should work for you.

Basically, if multiple buttons are pressed, the snake backtracks along itself, because first it registers that the key is valid, but then moves to execute the invalid key. So, even though logically it makes **NO FRIKKIN SENSE**, the snake backtracks.

This code simply tells it that if the snake backtracks (if the head coincides with the first or second part of the body), then the snake head should go back to its initial location, and resume its initial direction.

**Additional Code**:

To rotate the head correctly:

```
private void rotateCorr()
{
    if(p1x[0] = p1x[1] - DOT_SIZE)
    {
          // Your code to rotate p1 head to face the left
    }
    if(p1x[0] = p1x[1] + DOT_SIZE)
    {
          // Your code to rotate p1 head to face the right
    }
    if(p1y[0] = p1y[1] - DOT_SIZE)
    {
          // Your code to rotate p1 head to face the top
    }
    if(p1y[0] = p1y[1] + DOT_SIZE)
    {
          // Your code to rotate p1 head to face the bottom
    }

    // Now, for p2 snake:

    if(p2x[0] = p2x[1] - DOT_SIZE)
    {
          // Your code to rotate p2 head to face the left
    }
    if(p2x[0] = p2x[1] + DOT_SIZE)
    {
          // Your code to rotate p2 head to face the right
    }
    if(p2y[0] = p2y[1] - DOT_SIZE)
    {
          // Your code to rotate p2 head to face the top
    }
    if(p2y[0] = p2y[1] + DOT_SIZE)
    {
          // Your code to rotate p2 head to face the bottom
    }
}
```

If the head is above the second part, it is rotated to face the top, etc.

Comment: Because I made the same snake game, and faced the same glitch. There was even a solution which included an ArrayList, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Okay, so now I have edited it to include an explanation too.

Comment: Thank you. 1+ up for you

Comment: Thanks! Oh, and I'm a huge fan of your work. You seem to have answered  almost every question I see :)

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder thanks so much for your help, now almost all things works perfect! +1 for that answer, snake dont crash for itself anymore but now I have graphical issue, when i spam buttons like before the snake can move for example in a right direction with head directed to left site. Any solutions for that issue ?

Comment: I've edited it to rotate the snake head correctly. Also, if you feel this answer has helped you, don't forget to mark it as helpful! Just a gentle reminder :)

Comment: Coffeehouse, don't forget to use the `@` notation to notify @x3non that you've commented to him.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder Amazing work! Thanks a lot for help!!! Just one thing, in if statements u need to use "==", not "=" except that all works flavless :)

Comment: @x3non Sorry, I must have forgotten about the two '='. Will surely keep that in mind next time!